# What is wrong with this implementation of merge sort?

Tags: sorting, go, mergesort

I have been trying to implement merge sort algorithm the same way I have done in Python, but for some reason the outcome is not correct.

For example for this unsorted array [5, 2, 8, 3, 1, 7, 4, 11, 9, 10], I am getting outcome of [1 1 1 1 1 4 4 9 9 10]  instead of proper one. Can someone find out the issue in the function?

```
func merge_sort(array []uint) []uint {
    if len(array) > 1 {
        r := len(array) / 2
        L := array[:r]
        M := array[r:]

        L = merge_sort(L)
        M = merge_sort(M)

        i, j, k := 0, 0, 0
        for i < len(L) && j < len(M) {
            if L[i] <= M[j] {
                array[k] = L[i]
                i++
            } else {
                array[k] = M[j]
                j++
            }
            k++
        }
        for i < len(L) {
            array[k] = L[i]
            i++
            k++
        }
        for j < len(M) {
            array[k] = M[j]
            j++
            k++
        }
    }

    return array
}
```

Comment: Naive merge sort works only with an additional array used for the merge phase. Your code botches up the input arrays while merging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array`, `L`, and `M` are all referencing the same slice.

L[0] is referencing the same element as `array[0]`

So when you say:

```
array[k] = M[j]
```

You're overwriting what L[k] is referencing with M[j]

Simple fix is to introduce a new slice to return:

```
func merge_sort(array []uint) []uint {

    if len(array) > 1 {
        r := len(array) / 2
        L := array[:r]
        M := array[r:]

        L = merge_sort(L)
        M = merge_sort(M)

        result := make([]uint, len(array))

        i, j, k := 0, 0, 0
        for i < len(L) && j < len(M) {
            if L[i] <= M[j] {
                result[k] = L[i]
                i++
            } else {
                result[k] = M[j]
                j++
            }
            k++
        }
        for i < len(L) {
            result[k] = L[i]
            i++
            k++
        }
        for j < len(M) {
            result[k] = M[j]
            j++
            k++
        }
        return result
    }
    return array
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It has solved my issue. I was under the impression that I was creating a new slice for L and M which is not correct.

Comment: @taqi - I believe you could also replace your last two for `for` loops with the built-in `copy` function.  `copy(result[k:], L[i:])   k = k + len(L)-i` and `copy(result[k:], M[j:])`